# How to WHERE a param that is an array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have the following code:

```
MATCH 
    (a:Account {
        id : $account_id
    })
    -[:OWNER]->
    (p:Project)
    WHERE
        p.id IN $ids
RETURN p
```

Params

```
account_id : string
ids : Array<string>
```

How do I only return matching Project nodes where their id is contained in the $ids param?

Comment: Your query seems ok. Depend how your array looks like?

Comment: Your query should work as-is with your params if: `Account.id` and `Project.id` are actually stored as *properties* with *string* values, and your DB actually contains `OWNER` relationships that match the pattern.

Comment: @cybersam they are properties. It returns me nothing (not even null). But I was able to get it work by doing an `UNWIND $id as project_id` and then `WHERE` it.

Comment: Is it `$id` or `$ids`?

Comment: @cybersam `$ids` typo, but it shouldn't matter. It's working with UNWIND

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: @cybersam 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j ids are integers, not strings.
If with p.id you mean the internal id, try id(p)

Comment: These are *properties*, not `id(node)`